# Android MVVM как получить ответ от ViewModel во View

Tags: android, retrofit, rxjava

У меня есть активити, у нее есть viewmodel. Viewmodel во время инициализации скачивает с сервера с помощью retrofit данные в json. Эти данные преобразуются в список объектов во viewmodel. И теперь мне нужно использовать эти данные во View. Т.е. предупредить активити о том, что оно может использовать список из viewmodel. Пробовал это сделать с помощью интерфейсов, но интерфейсы не инициализируются в viewmodel.
Как можно это сделать по другому?

Comment: Используйте LiveData (самый простой и правильный вариант).

Comment: [Вот отличная статья на тему LiveData](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/527-urok-4-viewmodel.html) Ещё можно скачивать данные не в viewmodel, а в статическом методе, потом пулять ответ через интерфейс и потом уже сохранять в viewmodel. Т.е. если в viewmodel пусто то скачиваем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот вам небольшой пример как это делается.

**ViewModel:**

```
class ViewModel(private val dataSource: DataSource) :
    BaseViewModel() {

    val movieLiveData = MutableLiveData<MovieModel>()

    fun searchMovie(query: String) {
        backgroundScope.launch {
            val result: MovieModel = dataSource.get()
            movieLiveData.postValue(result)
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity:**

```
searchViewModel.movieLiveData.observe(this, Observer {movie ->
            handleResult(movie)
        })
```

Суть в том, что `ViewModel` ничего не должна знать о `View` (Activity/Fragment). `View` просто подписывается на `LiveData` которая находится внутри `ViewModel` и ждет оповещений. Когда ViewModel хочет отправить какой-то результат во `View` она просто постит значение в `LiveData`, а все подписчики его обрабатывают.

А вот [тут](https://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/architecture-components/27-course/architecture-components/527-urok-4-viewmodel.html) есть отличный урок как работать с ViewModel

Comment: Спасибо за пример :)